# Powerbuilder Excel-Cell like edit functionality on Datawindow Grid

Tags: grid, powerbuilder

I've been given a very unusual request of emulating excel-like editing functionality for my grid.

Here's the scenario: The users would like to be able to immediately change the content by clicking on the cell and typing whatever they wish. Currently, they have to double click on the cell to block select the content, and then type in their desired text to overwrite the cell contents. They'd like the intermediate step of double clicking to block select the text to be taken out. The editable cells hold only numbers.

So I have two options:

```
1. Automatically block select the cell contents as soon as the user clicks on it
2. Make the cell selection/edit behave the same way as excel
```

Given Powerbuilder's inherent limitations, I'm fairly convinced this is impossible without some wacky hack, but I'd like to hear ideas.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerBuilder does handle this with ease but you can look like a hero to your end-user now.
:)

**Auto Select Text in Datawindow Edit Fields**

In your datawindow painter, choose the column, then check the "auto select text" property. This will cause your text to be selected as soon as the field gets focus. Now the problem is that PB doesn't provide this feature for edit mask controls but you can get around that yourself using the below example.

**Auto Select Text in Edit Mast controls in Datawindow**

Add code to your datawindow *control* that checks for an edit mask field and highlights the text. The example could be put into the itemfocuschanged event of the datawindow control, or in your datawindow control ancestor.

```
// only if row present
if row > 0 then 
    if describe( dwo.Name + '.Edit.Style' ) = 'editmask' then
        // we found an edit mask so select the text in it
        this.selecttext(1,len(string(getitemstring(row,dwo.Name))))
    end if
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Auto Selection edit property?